# Cannot start docker daemon on Arch Linux (4.8.13-1-ARCH)

Tags: docker, archlinux

I have a fresh installation of 64bit Arch Linux on my notebook:

```
$ uname -a
Linux notebook 4.8.13-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Dec 9 07:24:34 CET 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I installed docker from community repository:

```
$ yaourt -S docker
```

Until here I had no problems. But if I try to start the docker daemon I get strange error messages with register addresses:

```
[root@notebook home]# systemctl start docker
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

[root@notebook home]# systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2016-12-18 10:27:32 CET; 11s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 9648 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// (code=exited, status=2)
 Main PID: 9648 (code=exited, status=2)
      CPU: 94ms

Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: r12    0x80
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: r13    0x1100
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: r14    0x23
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: r15    0x0
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: rip    0x6c988f
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: rflags 0x10246
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: cs     0x33
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: fs     0x0
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: gs     0x0
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

[root@notebook home]# journalctl -xe
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]:         /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2086 +0x1
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: goroutine 31 [chan receive]:
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: github.com/docker/docker/pkg/signal.Trap.func1(0xc4203691a0, 0xc420404600)
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]:         /build/docker/src/docker/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/signal/trap.go:32 +0x77
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: created by github.com/docker/docker/pkg/signal.Trap
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]:         /build/docker/src/docker/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/pkg/signal/trap.go:62 +0x1c8
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: goroutine 32 [chan receive]:
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: github.com/docker/docker/daemon.setupDumpStackTrap.func1(0xc4204267e0)
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]:         /build/docker/src/docker/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/daemon/debugtrap_unix.go:17 +0x53
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: created by github.com/docker/docker/daemon.setupDumpStackTrap
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]:         /build/docker/src/docker/.gopath/src/github.com/docker/docker/daemon/debugtrap_unix.go:20 +0xec
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: rax    0x6a09e667
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: rbx    0xbb67ae85
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: rcx    0x3c6ef372
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: rdx    0x510e527f
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: rdi    0x6a09e667
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: rsi    0x0
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: rbp    0x1807ce0
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: rsp    0xc4206d0cd8
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: r8     0xa54ff53a
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: r9     0x9b05688c
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: r10    0x1f83d9ab
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: r11    0x5be0cd19
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: r12    0x80
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: r13    0x1100
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: r14    0x23
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: r15    0x0
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: rip    0x6c988f
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: rflags 0x10246
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: cs     0x33
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: fs     0x0
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook dockerd[9648]: gs     0x0
Dez 18 10:27:32 notebook systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Is anyone out there facing the same issue? (Google didn't help this time). Is there anyone how has solved this or how could give me a hint?

Thanks in advance,
dymat

**EDIT** (response to @funilrys):

**/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
After=network.target docker.socket
Requires=docker.socket

[Service]
Type=notify
# the default is not to use systemd for cgroups because the delegate issues still
# exists and systemd currently does not support the cgroup feature set required
# for containers run by docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
# Having non-zero Limit*s causes performance problems due to accounting overhead
# in the kernel. We recommend using cgroups to do container-local accounting.
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitNPROC=infinity
LimitCORE=infinity
# Uncomment TasksMax if your systemd version supports it.
# Only systemd 226 and above support this version.
#TasksMax=infinity
TimeoutStartSec=0
# set delegate yes so that systemd does not reset the cgroups of docker containers
Delegate=yes
# kill only the docker process, not all processes in the cgroup
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After installation I tried to start docker daemon (`sudo systemctl start docker`)

Comment: A bit off topic but you should not use yaourt : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR_helpers#Comparison_table

Comment: Thanks Paul! I wasn't aware that yaourt is not the best choice and switched over to bauerbill. But I think my problem is not related to yourts insufficiancy since I removed and reinstalled docker (+all dependencies) by using native pacman... Anyway it's good to changed from yaourt.

Comment: Can you give us the result of `cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` ? What did you exactly did after installation ?

Comment: Remove docker: pacman -Rns docker,  then install docker using: curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh